# How Amazon Redshift rollback works under hood?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Does it work in metadata level or it manipuletes real data? For example, If I run delete and than rollback what actually happens? Does it store a copy of data and it potentially affect performance?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift uses MVCC for transaction management. See this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/169229/does-amazon-redshift-support-mvcc

Performance should be minimally impacted by a `ROLLBACK`.